# Save git commits on a branch to the file

Tags: git

Given the local branch (say 'test') - is it possible use some git magic to save commits on this branch to a file that I can send to the other developer who can then apply these commits to his branch? I know that there is a way to save every commit on a branch to the file, but not sure if it can be done for just commits on a local branch.

E.g. say master branch has commits 'a', 'b' and 'c' and my test branch has been created on 'c' and has commits 'd' and 'e':

```
 + (branch:master)
 |
 * commit:'a'
 |
 * commit:'b'
 |
 * commit:'c'
 |  \
...  + (branch:test)
     |
     * commit:'d'
     |
     * commit:'e' 
     x
```

So after generating that diff between 'test' and 'master' branches I want to have just 'd' and 'e' commits in that diff.
So the other developer can also create his own test branch from master, apply my diff and have commits 'd' and 'e' on his branch.

I know that this can be achieved by pushing changes to the remote branch, but for some reasons I would like to avoid doing that and yes, I know branches are cheap, but believe me I have good reasons to not to push these changes to the remote branch.

Comment: You might want to research `git bundle`, although the already accepted answer using `git format-patch` and `git am` is also useable. `git bundle` creates a single file that contains the specified commits, and that can be used as a "remote" repository to `git fetch` from.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a bundle solution. I personally found format-patch solution to be a perfect fit for my needs - it is simple and extremely easy to use - it generates a plain text file that can even be pasted as is into the email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your test branch do

```
git format-patch master --stdout > patch.diff
```

When applying

```
git am < patch.diff
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But your answer needs to be slightly corrected - 'git format-patch master --stdout > /tmp/patch' instead of 'git format-patch master > /tmp/patch'

Without --stdout format-patch will produce multiple patches (as many as you have commits in test branch).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way it so create a [bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). Not only does it move the diff your branch has, it move the actual commits.

The documentation has a good example but what you basically do is you create a bundle on one computer, transfer that to another computer and add it as a remote. From there you can merge, rebase, cherry-pick or anything you like.

What isn't clearly mentioned in the documentation is that it's fine to make a too big bundle, containing lots of commits that already exists on the target computer, as long as it has one in common it will work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command.

Try the following:

```
git diff test master
```

Comment: this won't save commits history - see line with 'So the other developer can also create his own test branch from master, apply my diff and have commits 'd' and 'e' on his branch.'